# How to create call from twilio helper liabrary in google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, twilio

I am trying to create an Outbound call from google app engine using the [Twilio Java helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/java/install)

Example:

```
private void createcall(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {

    String ACCOUNT_SID = "AC69000ff19655ca86c5a4ae027b886665";
    String AUTH_TOKEN = "bef9594c1e7f542b6e331bd7e50077d0";
    try {

        TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID,
                AUTH_TOKEN);
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("Url", "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml");
        params.put("To", "+919460952623");
        params.put("From", "+13072241210");

        CallFactory factory = client.getAccount().getCallFactory();
        Call call = factory.create(params);
        TwilioCapability capability = new TwilioCapability(ACCOUNT_SID,AUTH_TOKEN);
        capability.allowClientOutgoing("APf5250942ec073c9d08848990cbc0ff5e");
        resp.getWriter().write(capability.generateToken());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.warning(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

This example produces following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.decrypt(Lsun/security/ssl/CipherBox;)V
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:871)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1169)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1196)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.getSession(SSLSocketImpl.java:1920)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:91)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:397)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:573)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:425)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient.request(TwilioRestClient.java:394)
at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient.safeRequest(TwilioRestClient.java:524)
at com.twilio.sdk.resource.list.CallList.create(CallList.java:68)
at cleanify.CleanifyServlet.createcall(CleanifyServlet.java:111)
at cleanify.CleanifyServlet.doPost(CleanifyServlet.java:49)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:57)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:439)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:483)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:490)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:777)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$DoInTraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:754)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:345)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:337)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:487)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

2013-07-09 23:14:33.848
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.decrypt(Lsun/security/ssl/CipherBox;)V
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:871)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1169)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1196)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.getSession(SSLSocketImpl.java:1920)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:91)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:397)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:573)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:425)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient.request(TwilioRestClient.java:394)
at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient.safeRequest(TwilioRestClient.java:524)
at com.twilio.sdk.resource.list.CallList.create(CallList.java:68)
at cleanify.CleanifyServlet.createcall(CleanifyServlet.java:111)
at cleanify.CleanifyServlet.doPost(CleanifyServlet.java:49)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:57)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:439)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:483)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:490)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:777)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$DoInTraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:754)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:345)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:337)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:487)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

I don't know what the problem is, as billing is also enabled. I am doing everything according the docs of google app engine Integration with twilio.

Please Help Me!!

Comment: The current GAE helper library should include an App Engine-compatible Apache HTTP client.  Which versions of the Twilio SDK and App Engine SDK are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently twilio lib internally uses Apache HttpClient which need to be tweaked to be used on GAE: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava#Apache

Not sure if you will be able to inject your own `ClientConnectionManager` into Twillio lib though.

**Update:**

You can instantiate your own [HttpClinet with tweaks](http://peterkenji.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-apache-httpclient-4-with-google.html) to make it work on GAE and then [inject it into twilio lib](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/twilio/sdk/TwilioRestClient.java#L93):

```
twilioRestClient.setHttpclient(gaeHttpClient);
```