# how do I get a Twilio SID?

Tags: java, rest, asp.net-web-api, twilio, voip

A [question on dialing out with Twilio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17564775/262852) caught my attention, particularly:

```
capability.allowClientOutgoing("APf5250942ec073c9d08848990cbc0ff5e");
```

Looking at [sample code](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/applications):

```
// Install the Java helper library from twilio.com/docs/java/install
import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient;
import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestException;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.instance.Application;

public class Example { 

  // Find your Account Sid and Token at twilio.com/user/account
  public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "your_auth_token";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws TwilioRestException {
    TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

    // Get an object from its sid. If you do not have a sid,
    // check out the list resource examples on this page
    Application app = client.getAccount().getApplication("AP2a0747eba6abf96b7e3c3ff0b4530f6e");
    System.out.println(app.getSmsUrl());

  }
}
```

it's not much clearer.  The `ACCOUNT_SID` and `AUTH_TOKEN` are easy enough to copy/paste.  Where and how do I acquire the string to send?

[Javadocs](http://twilio.github.io/twilio-java/) say:

```
getApplication

public Application getApplication(String sid)

Get a given application instance by sid

Parameters:
    sid - The 34 character sid starting with AP
```

which just brings me back to where, and how, to acquire a SID to initiate a call.

Answer (score 4):

The application id asked is the TwiML application ID. These can be created either manually through browser https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/dev-tools/twiml-apps/add or programmatically using the Twilio REST API as described in https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/applications#list-post.

Mainly the application id will associate 2 urls: voice and message callback urls with your application. These are your application urls that Twilio will try to make requests when it gets new events or needs information. These urls should return [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml)

Answer (score 0):

A temporary SID is [in the portal for testing](https://www.twilio.com/login?g=/console/voice/dev-tools/test-credentials?&t=9c3152caff940bb810fd43c2d8965b1ac8b7560ac12f73712c7b0005efa3b7d6).  However, [this kluge executes](https://gist.github.com/THUFIR/f022faee0f2fd5c0e8af93c651045b31) by generating a new app with a new SID:

```
private void createApplication(TwilioRestClient client, String accountSID, String authToken, String fromNumber, String toNumber) {
    log.info("createApplication..");
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("FriendlyName", "Phone Me"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("VoiceUrl", "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("VoiceMethod", "GET"));
    ApplicationFactory appFactory = client.getAccount().getApplicationFactory();
    Application app = null;
    try {
        app = appFactory.create(params);
    } catch (TwilioRestException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Twilio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    String sid = app.getSid();
    log.info(sid);
    log.info("name\n" + app.getFriendlyName());
    log.info("sms url\n" + app.getSmsUrl());
    log.info("voice url\n" + app.getVoiceUrl());
    makeCall(client, accountSID, authToken, fromNumber, toNumber, sid);
}
```